# Detect and recover from credential deletion in Spring AMQP

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-config

We have a Spring Cloud Config setup, using Vault database backends (MySQL and RabbitMQ), which gives us the ability to inject generated credentials into properties such as:

- `spring.rabbitmq.username`
- `spring.rabbitmq.password`

When our app starts up we have a fresh set of Rabbit credentials, and we have the ability to request a new set on demand.

Since our Rabbit credentials are managed externally by Vault, they could be expired / deleted at any time during the app's life (this is also a resilience test scenario).

My question is how we can (effectively, reliably):

- Detect the expiry of the generated credentials
- Update our existing Spring AMQP `CachingConnectionFactory` with the new credentials.

We're working on the basis that this needs to be handled entirely client-side as a matter of resilience, even if the server was willing or able to send expiry notifications.

What we're struggling with is how to detect credential expiry so that we can then reconfigure the `CachingConnectionFactory`.

Possibilities include:

1. What we have now: a `ChannelListener` that builds a list of all newly-created 
   `Channel`s, and tries creating/deleting an anonymous `Queue` on each
   every x seconds, listening out for any `ShutdownSignalException`s via `ShutdownListener`
   that might have a 403 status code. This seems to work but is a bit complex, and we've seen concurrency issues doing anything non-trivial in the shutdown handler.
2. Hook into `CachingConnectionFactory` somehow. We tried working with a clone of the class but besides the complexity of that we just ended up with `RESOURCE_LOCKED` errors creating queues.
3. Something simpler and more lightweight, e.g. simply poll the broker every x seconds to validate the current credentials still exist.

Part of the problem is that `ACCESS_REFUSED` - what you get when `CachingConnectionFactory` tries to work with deleted credentials - is generally treated as a fatal misconfiguration error rather than part of any real workflow, or that can possibly be recovered from.

Is there a graceful solution here?

---

Using: Spring Boot 1.5.10-RELEASE, Spring Cloud Dalston SR4

---

**Update:**

On the `RabbitTemplate` side, no exception is thrown - with or without `RetryTemplate` - even when `CachingConnectionFactory` correctly detects `ACCESS_REFUSED` to the exchange that I'm sending to.

Configuration is:

```
spring
  rabbitmq:
    host: rabbitmq.service.consul
    port: 5672
    virtualHost: /
    template:
      retry:
        enabled: true
```

Code is:

```
@Autowired private RabbitTemplate rt;  // From RabbitAutoConfiguration

@Bean
public DirectExchange emailExchange() {
    return new DirectExchange("email");
}

public void sendEmail() {
    this.rt.send("email", "email.send", "test payload");
}
```

Application starts up, declaring the `email` exchange. The RabbitMQ UI shows my (generated) user and connection to the exchange, which is fine at startup. I then simulate credential expiry by manually deleting that user using the UI before running a local test to call `sendEmail()` email above.

No exceptions are thrown or errors logged as a result of the `RabbitTemplate` call, but the following (expected) error is logged:

> [AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672] ERROR
>   o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: channel error;
>   protocol method: #method(reply-code=403,
>   reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - access to exchange 'email' in vhost '/'
>   refused for user
>   'cert-configserver-75c3ae60-da76-3058-e7df-a7b90ef72171', class-id=60,
>   method-id=40)

Short of checking credentials before all `RabbitTemplate.send()` calls, I'd like to know if there's any way to catch the `ACCESS_REFUSED` error during send so that I can refresh credentials as I do for listeners, and give `RetryTemplate` a chance to retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much experimentation and debugging, I took [Artem Bilan's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49155945/954442) and adopted the [RabbitMQ Event Exchange Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html).

So now, instead of trying to track `ShutdownSignalException` and `ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent` events across Spring and Rabbit code, between `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` on one hand, and `RabbitTemplate` on the other, I simply subscribe to an exchange and let my new `@RabbitListener` notify me of credential issues. This without any other moving parts or bean declarations, without any synchronization issues or blocked threads, and generally going with the flow of autoconfiguration rather than fighting it.

All I now need is:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitProperties;
import org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.RefreshEndpoint;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import static org.springframework.amqp.core.ExchangeTypes.TOPIC;

@Component
public class ReuathenticationListener {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReuathenticationListener.class);

    @Autowired private RabbitProperties rabbitProperties;
    @Autowired private RefreshEndpoint refreshEndpoint;
    @Autowired private CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @RabbitListener(
        id = "credential_expiry_listener",
        bindings = @QueueBinding(value = @Queue(value="credentials.expiry", autoDelete="true", durable="false"),
            exchange = @Exchange(value="amq.rabbitmq.event", type=TOPIC, internal="true", durable="true"),
            key = "user.#")
    )
    public void expiryHandler(final MessageHeaders headers) {
        final String key = (String) headers.get("amqp_receivedRoutingKey");
        // See: https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html
        if (!key.equals("user.deleted") &&
            !key.equals("user.authentication.failure")) {
            return;
        }

        final String failedName = (String) headers.get("name");
        final String prevUsername = rabbitProperties.getUsername();

        if (!failedName.equals(prevUsername)) {
            log.debug("Ignore expiry of unrelated user: " + failedName);
            return;
        }

        log.info("Refreshing Rabbit credentials...");
        refreshEndpoint.refresh();
        log.info("Refreshed username: '" + prevUsername + "' => '" + rabbitProperties.getUsername() + "'");

        connectionFactory.setUsername(rabbitProperties.getUsername());
        connectionFactory.setPassword(rabbitProperties.getPassword());
        connectionFactory.resetConnection();

        log.info("CachingConnectionFactory reset, reconnection should now begin.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have raised a JIRA on the matter: https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-804

Answer (score 1):

For such a scenario a listener container emits a `ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent`. You can listen to this one, check its `reason` and exception and decide to `stop()` the container and do something else you need. Then `start()` it again to consume the broker with fresh credentials.

On the `RabbitTemplate` side there is just need to `try...catch` the call and analyze an exception for the same reason.

That's not what I tried so far, but this is my best feeling how to deal with the `ACCESS_REFUSED` state. You really can't do anything on the matter from the `CachingConnectionFactory` perspective.

**UPDATE**

My application is like this:

```
spring.rabbitmq.username=test
spring.rabbitmq.password=test
spring.rabbitmq.template.retry.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.template.retry.initial-interval=1ms
logging.level.org.springframework.retry=DEBUG
```

---

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So49155945Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(So49155945Application.class, args);
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = applicationContext.getBean(RabbitTemplate.class);

        try {
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("foo", "foo");
        }
        catch (AmqpException e) {
            System.err.println("Error during sending: " + e.getCause().getCause().getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

And this is what I have in the console when I run this app for that non-existing user:

```
Error during sending: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.
```

**UPDATE 2**

What I found also as we can make these props:

```
spring.rabbitmq.publisher-confirms=true
spring.rabbitmq.template.mandatory=true
```

And then add a `rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback()` and our rejected message for the async send will be rejected. However it still is a async callback, similar to the mentioned `ChannelListener`. There is really nothing to do from the Spring AMQP perspective. Everything is an async nature of the AMQP protocol and might really need some "fail fast" hook from the Rabbit Client library.

Please, ask such a question on the `rabbitmq-users` Google group. That's the place where RabbitMQ engineers hang outs.

**UPDATE 3**

As the solution for such events on the Broker the [Event Exchange Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html) can be used. The particular `user.deleted` or `user.password.changed` events are emitted by the Broker.

Comment: On the `RabbitTemplate` side, no exception is actually thrown inside the `RetryTemplate`. I can see `CachingConnectionFactory` logging the `ACCESS_REFUSED` but sending just silently carries on, without retry.

Comment: Exactly the same by the look of it.

Comment: Any simple code to reproduce? What should I do from the `RabbitTemplate` perspective to observe similar behavior and may be see that `ACCESS_REFUSED` logs on the matter?

Comment: I added an UPDATE to my answer. Unfortunately it works as I excepted. And also I see all those 3 retry attempts

Comment: The difference is that in your example, RT's `connectionFactory.createConnection()` has to create a new conn, and fails straightaway with `AuthenticationFailureException`. In my case, `CachingConnectionFactory` pulls a cached one, and doesn't test it, so we get the underlying failure but no exception.

Comment: And since I'm being reactive rather than proactive in refreshing the ConnFactory, my code doesn't know before the `RabbitTemplate` send that the ConnFactory needs that refresh. So I neither know in advance nor can intercept the above exception at the RT level. Feels like I need to replace/override either the RT or the CachingConnFactory...

Comment: Now I see what you mean. Thanks. Investigating and discussing with Gary Russell. What I can suggest is like `CachingConnectionFactory.addChannelListener(ChannelListener)` and handle that `onShutDown()` which happens in this case. However I agree that it still isn't good for the blocking `send()` operation: we don't know what happened and may lose the data.

Comment: Please, see an `UPDATE 2` in my answer.

Comment: Re: `ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent`, surely this will only be thrown when a container has to process an event but gets a problem? I'm stuck because the container's user is deleted but I can't discover then until it's used, not proactively, e.g. via some kind of ping or heartbeat on the connection or channels.

Comment: You can consider to use `com.rabbitmq.http.client.Client.getUser(String username)` to ping if the user is there or not: https://github.com/rabbitmq/hop

Comment: I hoped we could ping the user, and Hop does that - thanks. Only issue is that we'd have to inject long-lived Admin credentials into individual services to do client-side checks, which'd probably be forbidden. Alternatively the Cloud Config server could use Hop for scheduled checks and send remote refreshes. Both of these a long way from the original solution though!

Comment: M-m-m. You know looks like this can help you: https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html

Comment: Aha, that looks like the perfect solution. I'll give it a try!

Comment: Yep! I have just opened it for myself this morning! :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help with this - Event Exchange worked really well and saved a lot of code!

Comment: I wouldn't have got there without your help, but I've posted a new standalone answer that sums up all I needed to do, which is quite different from where we started out. TBH I don't really know why I couldn't solve this completely in-code, but hopefully the plugin approach will help others.